# how to find matching element using xslt with the given criteria

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to find the largest element using length and value

my input xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<section>
<root>
<data><label.designator>31.</label.designator></data>
<data><label.designator>31.5.</label.designator></data>
<data><label.designator>49.5.</label.designator></data>
<data><label.designator>50.</label.designator></data>
</root>
</section>
```

I am trying with below xslt code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>


  <xsl:template match="root">
       
        <xsl:variable name="Length">
               <xsl:for-each select="data/label.designator">
                  <xsl:sort select="string-length(.)" order="descending" data-type="number"/>
                  <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                     <xsl:value-of select="string-length(.)"/>
                  </xsl:if>
               </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:variable>
            Max string length is: <xsl:value-of select="$Length"/><br/>


        <xsl:variable name = "list" select="child::data[last()]/label.designator/string-length(.) = $Length" />
         Value is : <xsl:value-of select="$list"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

here I am getting true or false instead i should get the value, in my case it is 49.5 (it is matching both criteria's  longest(i have 2 here 31.5. and 49.5.) & biggest(out of 2 49.5. is the highest one)

expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<section>
    Max string length is: 5<br/> and value is : 49.5.
</section>
```

Comment: In your example, both `31.5.` and `49.5.` have the max string length of 5. How do you intend to determine which one of these has the greater value, given that neither of them is a number?

Comment: @michael.hor257k yes you are correct, but if i remove last dot(.) then it will become as numbers.  I may be wrong.. right now i am thinking in that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's acceptable to remove the trailing period in order to calculate the max value, then you could do:

**XSLT 3.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
expand-text="yes">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/section">
    <xsl:variable name="data" select="root/data/label.designator" />
    <xsl:variable name="max-len" select="max($data/string-length())" />
    <xsl:variable name="max-val" select="max($data[string-length()=$max-len]/replace(., '\.$', ''))" />
    
    <section>Max string length is: {$max-len}<br/> and value is : {$max-val}</section>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<section>Max string length is: 5<br/> and value is : 49.5</section>
```

However, this result shows a discrepancy between the original string-length of 5 and the adjusted value's string-length of 4.

---

Demo: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVAkJ5b

Comment: thankyou so much, this will suite for my requirement

Answer (score 0):

At https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#highest-lowest you will find example code for a function called `eg:highest()`. If you add this function to your stylesheet, you can then call `eg:highest(//label.designator, string-length#1)` to obtain the element or elements with greatest string-length.